# Cross Object Picklist

Tags: formula, cross-object, recordtriggeredflow

I have two objects, Object A and Object B that both have a custom picklist field for Status. Object B has a lookup relationship to Object A. I want to make it so that whenever the status field on Object A is changed or vise versa that it will update to the same status on the other object. I have been trying to figure out a record triggered flow but can't seem to get it to work. I thought about a cross object formula but they don't work on picklists. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I hope with single record triggered flow it may not work. You may need two record triggered flow on two objects I guess.

Comment: You need to think about what happens if child1 of Object B is changed to status X while child 2 of the same parent has its status changed to Y in the _same transaction_. Who wins?